# Alter redirect layout to open in new tab Sharepoint

Tags: page-layout, redirect

I'm trying to alter a redirect page layout so that when the redirect happens it will open in a new tab.
I believe this section is the part that controls the redirect.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<PublishingWebControls:RedirectControl SecondsBeforeRedirect="5" runat="server"/>
<div class="redirect">
    <SharePointWebControls:FormField FieldName="RedirectURL" runat="server"/>
    <PublishingWebControls:RichImageField FieldName="PublishingRollupImage" runat="server"/>
    <PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server" CssClass="edit-mode-panel title-edit">
        <SharePointWebControls:TextField runat="server" FieldName="Title"/>
    </PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
</div>
```

How do I alter this to allow the redirect to open in a new tab?

Answer (score 0):

I realized later that my question didn't actually make sense. It's not a redirect if you're opening a new tab.

I found that if I added a FieldValue with RedirectUrl fieldname, then it would create an anchor with the href that I wanted.

So, I added another EditModePanel with display on, and added a hidden div with an id of redirect-url. Within it, I placed the RedirectUrl field. Then I added javascript to gather that url, and open a new window.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<PublishingWebControls:RedirectControl SecondsBeforeRedirect="5" 
runat="server"/>
<div class="redirect">
    <SharePointWebControls:FormField FieldName="RedirectURL" 
    runat="server"/>
    <PublishingWebControls:RichImageField FieldName="PublishingRollupImage" 
    runat="server"/>
    <PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server" CssClass="edit-mode-
    panel title-edit">
        <SharePointWebControls:TextField runat="server" FieldName="Title"/>
    </PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>

    <PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server" 
    PageDisplayMode="Display">
        <div style="display:none;" id="redirect-url">
            <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue FieldName="RedirectURL" 
            runat="server" />
        </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var url = $("#redirect-url a").attr("href");
        var target = "_blank";
        window.open(url, target);
    });
    </script>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```